# How to uniquely identify and click on desired link using webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I have this html

```
<a class="level1 static" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','2')" tabindex="-1">2</a>

<a class="level1 static" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','5')" tabindex="-1">5</a>

<a class="level1 static" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','6')" tabindex="-1">6</a>
```

each a tag represents a number hyperlink. What I want to do is use webdriver to find a tag that has a number and click on it. for example the webdriver should find a tag that has 2 and click on it. So I tried this code

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('2').click
```

and this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick*='__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','2')']").click
```

but nothing happens. How do I uniquely identify and click on desired number using webdriver.

Comment: add `()` to invoke a method: `driver.find_element_by_link_text('2').click()`

Comment: @jone2 , are you getting any error on clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this by xpath:
    //a[text()='2']